# Difference between Reflexive and Symmetric in Discrete Maths

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

**Difference between Reflexive and Symmetric in Discrete Maths?**

This is what I understand:

Reflexive -> `<a,a=a>, <b,b=b>` uses `=` to describe.

Symmetric -> `<a,b>, <b,a>` uses `≤, ≥, =` to describe.

Transitive -> `<a,b>, <b,c>, <a,c>` uses `<, >, =` to describe.

But why is this is a symmetric `<1,1>, <2,2>, <3,3>, <4,4>, <5,5>`?

Comment: A relation on a set $S$ is a collection of pairs $(a, b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $S$.  Those particular named properties are statements about which pairs are present in the relation.

Answer (score 3):

A relation is *reflexive* if, for all $a$, $a$ is "related" to $a$ ($aRa$ is true).

A relation is *symmetric* if, whenever $aRb,$ then $bRa$ (so $\le$ is not symmetric because if $a\le b$ it does not follow that $b\le a$, but equality is symmetric).

A relation is *transitive* if, given $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$. e.g. if $a|b$ and $b|c$ then $a|c$ so divisibility is transitive.

Comment: so what operators can I use to describe symmetric? =, < and >?
and am I correct to use =, < and > to describe transitive?

so basically both symmetric and transitive are both reflexive then?

Comment: Assume $a<b$.  Then is $b<a$?  What does that tell you about the symmetry of $<$?

Comment: $<$ is a transitive relation.  But $a\not<a$ so it is not reflexive.  None of the above properties imply the others.

Comment: Examples of symmetry are $=,\equiv \pmod m$

Comment: @KreasSueq "describe" I wouldn't use here. Maybe you mean: what are typical examples of symmetric relations, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric means that for every $(a,b)\in R$ also $(b,a)\in R$

$(c,c)$ is symetric with itself.

(Reflexive means that such $(c,c)$ exists at all, and does not necessarily mean that the relation is symmetric)

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence. Can you provide an example where (c,c) is reflexive but not symmetric?